# Get Caller in callback JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any way to get $('#div') inside callback function? $('#div') changes

```
var param = {
    a: 'haha'
}

$('#div').load('/foo.html', param, foo())

function foo() {
   var div = caller?  // this variable should be "$('#div')[0]"
}
```

Comment: Note, in your edit, foo() will be called before load() - should be `.load('/foo.html', param, foo)`

Answer (score 1):

`this` will be the element that `.load` was called on, eg:

```
$('#div').load('/foo.html', param, function() { $(this).show() })
```

---

Your edit to the question translates as:

```
var fooResult = foo();
$('#div').load('/foo.html', param, fooResult);
```

So in this case, no, because foo() will have already been called.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete

> The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection,
> and `this` is set to each DOM element in turn.

So:

```
var $div = $(this); // the jQuery object representing the div
var div = this; // the HTMLElement representing the div
```